# Ufw, can i block port 22? (ssh port changed)

Tags: ssh, vnc, ufw

I've changed the ssh port (just in case), now I was thinking to close port 22, to block immediately with ufw anyone trying to do damage on my server...

But when i initially enabled ssh i enabled a profile called OpenSSH, and i got the doubt it can do other things too.
with this:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

For example my vps can be accessed with vnc from provider control panel, if i close port 22 i risk to block vnc too? Or do other damage?

And how should i do it now?

```
sudo ufw deny ssh
sudo ufw deny OpenSSH
sudo ufw deny 22/tcp
```

Comment: Now that you have changed the `ssh` port away from 22, can you still access the provider's VNC? If so, then **probably** blocking port 22 should not matter. You can use `sudo ufw deny ssh`. This will just block port 22, not the new port you have assigned for `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

> VNC

First of all, VNC doesn't run of port `22`, but from ports `5500`, `5800`, `5900` *(by default)*, so you're fine

You mention a provider's *VNC* connection, but that connection doesn't make any communication to your server, at all, what you're seeing on your screen during those sessions is the *monitor* output from your machine and what you're sending is only literal keys and mouse input.

So, you can close those ports without fear of bricking that function

Comment: VNC can be tunneled through `ssh`, and then it will use whatever port `ssh` uses (22 by default). So, I guess it depends on how the VPS provider has implemented VNC.